# Open ASCII data using syntax file

Tags: r, ascii, read.table, read.csv

I have about 300 ASCII datasets all of which with a unique syntax file. In the syntax file, it is expressed what I think the separation of columns is.

I am very confused about how to use both files (the dataset file and the syntax file) to open the data properly in R. I am adding a picture of how the data (DA) and syntax file (ES) look like. The data and syntax can be downloaded here:

http://cis.es/cis/opencms/EN/formulario.jsp?dwld=/Microdatos/MD2763.zip

[image]

I thought about using regex to get how the columns are separated, but the patterns vary somewhat across datasets, so I am guessing that is probably an easier way to do this.
The syntax file seems to be something created automatically by some software, so I wonder if R has a function that receives as input both the data (DA) and the syntax (ES) to import the data properly.

Comment: At the bottom of the form, the English INSTRUCTIONS is not available, but the [Spanish](http://datos.cis.es/pdf/Instrucciones%20MD/ES_Instrucciones%20MD.pdf) ones are (you can probably send them an email for the English version). My Spanish is bad, but I understand this: "Programa de sintaxis de lectura del fichero de microdatos para trabajar con **SPSS** (ESxxxx)." So it's an SPSS format, you might be able to use the package `haven`.

Comment: And if you don't find a ready-made function, it shouldn't be too hard to write. You can find [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/syn_data_list_examples.html) the way to interpret the column names (178 columns described between `DATA LIST` and `VARIABLE LABEL`).